# Retagging [queries] -> [query]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 287 questions in [queries](/questions/tagged/queries).  There are 12,400~ in [query](/questions/tagged/query).  I'd like to go ahead and start retagging questions to all use [query](/questions/tagged/query) and hopefully encourage a qualified user to start a wiki for the tag as well.

Assuming no objections let's do a little retagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and merged the tags and created the synonym [queries](/questions/tagged/queries) -> [query](/questions/tagged/query) so the plural tag doesn't get recreated.  Someone definitely should update the info wiki for [query](/questions/tagged/query).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'll accept this as the answer once the time limit is up.